# VBA - PowerPoint - Insert custom bullets

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I hope you are doing well. I am trying to create a code to insert the following bullets within the selected text box

### [image: Expected]

The font used is Wingdings and the characters are

1. 140
2. 141
3. 142
4. 143
5. 144
6. 145
7. 146
8. 147
9. 148

I tried with the following code :

```
Sub bulletlist()
    With ActiveSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.bullet
        .Type = ppBulletUnnumbered
        .Character = 140
        With .Font
            .Name = "Wingdings"
            .Size = 44
            .Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End With
    End With
With ActiveSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.bullet
        .Type = ppBulletUnnumbered
        .Character = 141
        With .Font
            .Name = "Wingdings"
            .Size = 44
            .Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End With
    End With
With ActiveSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.bullet
        .Type = ppBulletUnnumbered
        .Character = 142
        With .Font
            .Name = "Wingdings"
            .Size = 44
            .Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End With
    End With
With ActiveSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.bullet
        .Type = ppBulletUnnumbered
        .Character = 143
        With .Font
            .Name = "Wingdings"
            .Size = 44
            .Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

But powerpoint returns an error on that code. 
Do you have any ideas?

Thank you for your time
Naxso

Comment: Powerpoint does not have an `ActiveSlide`.

Comment: I suspect you need .character = Chr$(142) etc to convert your ascii number into an actual character, but I don't have powerpoint here to test it

Comment: `RGB(255, 255, 255)` is white. Did you want black - `RGB(0, 0, 0)` or just `vbBlack`? (For more see the [`RGB` documentation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rgb-function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be setting changes on the **slide layout**, not the slide. Otherwise, you'll have to rerun the macro on every new slide you create that has this numbering style.

But you're reinventing the wheel, because PowerPoint already includes this numbering style. In the XML, it's called circleNumWdBlackPlain. (Here's my article on PowerPoint numbering styles, with more detail: [OOXML Hacking: PowerPoint Numbering Styles](http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2017/06/xml-hacking-powerpoint-numbering-styles/)

The VBA to set this:

```
Sub NumberStyling()
  With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet
    .Type = msoBulletNumbered
    .Style = msoBulletcircleNumWdBlackPlain
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi John, thanks a lot this is great, the code works well. The reason why I do not want to set it on the slide layout is because I have to change of slide layout each time. I prefer to re run the macro.
How can I do if I want to set a personal selection of characters ** in VBA **?
For e.g ```First bullet I want Windings character 140 ; Second Bullet I want Windings character 500 : Third bullet Police Arial character 500 ?```
This would be great. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ActiveSlide`, try to refer to the "ActiveSlide" this way:

```
Dim activeSlide as Slide
set activeSlide = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
```